# Interactively enter non-printable characters

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I know how to enter non-printable chars into a command by using echo:

```
echo -e '\xde\xad\xbe\xef' | some-cmd
```

But what if the `some-cmd` command is interactive and may ask for input later? I would like to be able to continue entering non-printable characters as backslash-escaped sequences.

So, for example, given the following Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

while True:
    s = input("> ")
    print(s, len(s))
```

I'd like to interact with it the following way:

```
$ ./io.py 
> \x41
A 1
> \x42
B 1
> \xde
Þ 1
> \xad
\xad 1
```

i.e. I enter escaped values and they get interpreted before being fed into  a program.

Comment: Change keyboard settings? Do you want to enter unicode characters? or do you want to send some arbitrary values via keyboard entry?

Comment: completely arbitrary bytes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your exact requirement, but maybe you want this:

```
$ awk --non-decimal-data '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%c", (0+("0x"$i))}' | some-cmd
```

Then you can enter the hex values separated by spaces/tabs/newlines at the prompt.
Sample usage:

```
$ awk --non-decimal-data '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%c", (0+("0x"$i))}' | sponge | sed '1s/^/Output:\n/'
40
30 31 41
a 61 62 a

Output:
@01A
ab
```

- 0x40 == '@',
- 0x30 == '0',
- 0x31 == '1',
- 0x41 == 'A',
- 0x61 == 'a',
- 0xa == '\n'  and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately it does not work for my use-case. I clarified the question

Comment: So, is this `io.py` a working solution for you? If yes, then add it as an answer and you can accept your own answer after 2 days. If not, let us know, what help do you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r line; do echo -e $line; done | some_cmd
```